# Does Client App also need api key or token to access the Rest backend?

Tags: c#, rest, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi

Does an endpoint in rest api which is responsible for user authentication is open (public) or even a key ,token further required to access this endpoint by the front end.

I am making REST backend with ASP.NET Core 8 webapi  & front with Blazor webassm.

Comment: Well that depends on what you want to have. Usally the login can be accessed by Anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Your authentication (login/signin) api will not be open for public as it will be the entry point to your application. Exposing your Api to public which will mean exposing it other malicious users, who will do all sorts of things with your system, matter of fact any kind of attacks can be made, even when you don't have much data, or sensitive data it could be dangerous.

In Asp.Net Core 8 blazor supports the [Antiforgery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0%5D) that will help defend against cross-site requests.
Decorate your endpoint with attribute

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

The Blazor EditForm already supports this you can read about it according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0%5D)

You can read more about the AntiForgery [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/validateantiforgerytoken-in-asp-net-core/)